# Way to reduce compiled DLL bloat when using Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We have been using EF with Code First Migrations for a while, and our DLL has grown to almost 10 megabytes. This may not seem like a big deal, but every time we add a migration to our project, it's causing the DLL to grow.

I've found that excluding the migrations from the project file works okay, and doesn't harm anything (as long as your databases already have those migrations). Is that an acceptable way of handling the bloat, or is there some reason they need to stick around? Or is there an alternative way of keeping the files there in the project but not letting them bloat things so much?

Comment: We are having the same problem, but always thought that there was no way around.

Comment: In EF6.0 you can put your migrations into a separate project. Using the `-ContextProjectName` parameter of the enable-migrations command.

Comment: @nemesv hrm. would you need to include that project in your deploy for everything to still work?

Comment: @nemesv the `-ContextProjectName` doesn't exist for `Add-Migration` how can you add migration to that project?

Comment: @AlexandreRondeau - it's actually part of the `Enable-Migrations` command.

Comment: @Nicholas No, you don't have to include the project with migrations into your deploy package. No "real" project should reference that one. But you do need it for `Update-Database`.

Comment: We use [database projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xee70aty%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with a code first approach. At first I was skeptical (they are very verbose and can be fiddly) but must say that I'm a convert now and it's the only way to reliably manage database change deployments!

Comment: We're up to 45MB here.. the dll is overwhelmingly full of base64 migration data..

Comment: 30MB here.  I always wondered why deployment hangs so long on that particular file.  Migrations are definitely to blame, because there's otherwise not much in it.

Comment: @IliaBarahovski you really should respond with an answer below so I can mark it as accepted - we wound up using the separate project and it works great

Comment: @NicholasHead done as requested. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to include the project with migrations into your deploy package. No "real" project should reference that one. But you do need it for `Update-Database`.

(Originally answered in comment.)